# How to retrieve the offset to the embedded JPG in a nef-file (Nikon raw format) in Lazarus

Tags: jpeg, offset, lazarus

Goodmorning,

with my Nikon DSLR, I always shoot raw. I'd like to import my nef's in an import-folder and copy them from there with a name, prefixed by the date taken. In Lazarus I've created a class named TMyNef and I've managed to retrieve the date taken, ISO, Shutterspeed, F-Stops, exposure program, maker, model and focal length. I'm struggling with the offset to the embedded JPG. I need this because the Lazarus TImage-component doesn't support the NEF-format, but it can display JPG's perfectly. Every NEF has an embedded JPG (you see on the back of the camera), hidden in the PreviewTAG of the NEF. Basically, a NEF is almost the same as a TIFF. A Tiff uses IFD-s to store meta-information. So, I studied lots of sites about tiff, exif, Exiftool (Phil Harvey), DCRaw (Dave Coffin)  I've used Exiftool.exe to analyse my nef's. I've even called "Exiftool.exe -b"  within my program, but it's to slow. 
Shortly, it comes down to:

1. Open the file
2. Read the header
3. Search for tag 0x8769 (the EXIF-tag)
4. If not found -> exit
5. Goto the offset where the EXIF-IFD starts
6. Search for tag 0x927C (The makernotes)
7. If not found -> exit
8. Goto to the offset where the MAKERNOTES-IFD starts
9. Read the Makernotes header
10. Search for tag 0x011, the Nikon Preview IFD
11. If not found -> Exit
12. Goto to the Nikon Preview IFD
13. Search for tags 0x201 (Start of the embedded JPG) and
    tag 0x202 (Size of the embedded JPG)
14. If not found -> exit
15. Goto the start of the embedded jpg.
16. Read JPGSIZE-bytes from the file and copy them to a TMemorystream,
    called Fms
17. Perform a Image1.Picture.LoadFromStream(Fms)

Summarized:
Open nef, search tag x08769, search 0x927C, search 0x0011, search 0x0201.

"Goto" means in the case: move the filepointer to the given offset.

Unfortunately, I've haven't been able the retrieve the offset of the embedded JPG. My program gives entirely different values than Phil Harvey's "Exiftool".
Jumping to "Phil's offset" and read until 0xFFD9 or read the amount of bytes given in tag 0x202, display's a perfect picture, going to the offset my program found and read until 0xFFD9, Lazarus says: Unsupported picture-format.
In the several IFD's I've found the meta-data I needed, so I took that along with me.

Does anyone know a way to retrieve the correct offset to the embedded JPG in a NEF? Or is there another way to display a NEF via the TImage-component in Lazarus?

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Martin
(Intel I5, 8Gb, Windows 10, Nikon Codec loaded, Lazarus 1.8)

Comment: Beginning of exif is 0x45, 0x78, 0x69 (E, X, I), not 0x8769

Answer (score 0):

Offsets within Exif structures usually are relative to the beginning of the TIFF header in front of the first Exif tag. This is true for jpeg and tiff files, not sure about NEF.